# how to pass object level data to d3.scale.linear callback?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to pass a data attribute, ie, Object.data to a d3 call back used to generate scale.

```
  renderScatter: () ->
    $("#render").click =>
      @target.selectAll("svg").selectAll("circle")
        .data(@data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (d) =>
          @xScale(d[0])
        )
        .attr("cy", (d) -> d[1])
        .attr("r", (d) ->
          Math.sqrt(200 - d[1])
        )
```

`@xScale(d[0])` refers to the below function

```
  xScale:
    d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([ 1, d3.max(@data, (d) -> d[1]) ])
      .range([ 0, 200 ])
```

`Object.data` points to an array of arrays, ie, [[1,2],[3,4]] but when I try to call @renderScatter() with the correctly set scaling information, i'm getting an error message that seems to indicate the scope inside xScale() doesn't recognize @data.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

The full Coffeescript class is below.

```
class ScatterPlot
  constructor: (width, height, target) ->
    @confirmation = ->
      console.log "scatter is working"
    @data= []
    @width = width || "100"
    @height = height || "200"
    @target = d3.select(target)
    @callActions()

  callActions: () ->
    @generateTitle()
    @generateData()
    @drawScatterSvg()
    @renderScatter()
    @renderLabels()

  generateTitle: () ->
    $("#scatterButton").click =>
      @target.append("h5")
        .text($("#scatterName").val())

  generateData: ()->
    $("#generateData").click =>
      if @data.length is 0
        _(10).times =>
          @data.push([Math.round(Math.random() * 325 + 5), Math.round(Math.random()*150 + 20)])
        $("#data").text(@data)

  drawScatterSvg: () ->
    $("#drawSVG").click =>
      console.log @target
      @target.append("svg")
        .attr("width", @width + "px")
        .attr("height", @height + "px")
        .classed("scatter", true)

  renderScatter: () ->
    $("#render").click =>
      @target.selectAll("svg").selectAll("circle")
        .data(@data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", (d) =>
          @xScale(d[0])
        )
        .attr("cy", (d) -> d[1])
        .attr("r", (d) ->
          Math.sqrt(200 - d[1])
        )

  renderLabels: ->
    $("#labels").click =>
      @target.selectAll("svg").selectAll("text")
        .data(@data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text( (d) ->
          d[0] + "," + d[1] )
        .attr("x", (d) -> d[0])
        .attr("y", (d) -> d[1])
        .attr("fill", "red")

  xScale:
    d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([ 1, d3.max(@data, (d) -> d[1]) ])
      .range([ 0, 200 ])

plot = new ScatterPlot("500", "200", "#scatter")
```

Comment: Where exactly is that error message coming from?